# Tabulator. Sending data on server

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabulator

I would like to get info in global how the sending data (table) to server works. On Tabulator web page I have find documentation how to retrieve-load data from server, but my search abut how to get data on sever as first has not gave me any result.

Can you pleas clarify  how the sending data on server is performed?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_ajax_examples.asp

Comment: Take a look on this. Does this help you?

Comment: I am using Tabulator.min.js  library.  In general I have find out main about it. But to proceed and to develop my project I am missing how to load data on server. I know how  to use Ajax in both direction (send on server and get data from server), if we are talking about Ajax in general, but I can't find out how to use it with Tabulator.

Comment: It is not problem for me to use json  for "select" tag drop-down list to send all data about it on server and then retrieving it back, but  for all the table (cosole.log  when table displayed as innerHtml says  that it is 17.3 kb of data)  I need  something more complex...

Comment: var dataAll = table.getData();
    var jsonDataAll=JSON.stringify(dataAll);
    
    var selectedData = table.getSelectedData();
    var selectedDataJson=JSON.stringify(selectedData);
    console.log(selectedDataJson);

Comment: As I have not find direct instructions on Tabulator page. I am proceeding as next. var dataAll = table.getData();
    var jsonDataAll=JSON.stringify(dataAll);
    console.log(jsonDataAll);
    var selectedData = table.getSelectedData();
    var selectedDataJson=JSON.stringify(selectedData);
    console.log(selectedDataJson);

Answer (score 0):

Next is was I looking for:

```
dataAll = table.getData();
```